# getting path value from bean using struts2

Tags: struts2

```
public class product {
    private String name;
    private String path;
    // and getter setter of attributes
}
```

I want to get the `path` value from the bean and give this path value in "img src" tag.
I know that  print the path attribute value but my question is that use this path value in img tag to upload this image

Comment: i know that how to print the path attribute value but my question is that use this path value in img tag to upload this image

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `ModelDriven` with a `product` as the model:

```xml
<img src="<s:property value='path'/>"/> 
<%-- You can also use JSP EL --%>
<img src="${path}"/>
```

If there's an action property instead, use normal bean notation:

```xml
<img src="<s:property value='product.path'/>"/> 
<img src="${product.path}"/>
```